# Where is the php file, that does the checks for login information?

Tags: login, security, wp-login-form, authentication

I would like to add some additional checks into my wordpress website's username and password authentication function for specific usernames, but I cannot find the correct php file...

```
/* I would like to do something like this */
if ($username == "testuser_with_no_rights") {
    /* ... */
}
else { 
    /* do everything as it was defined originally */ 
}
```

So, basically, **where is the php file, that does the checks for login information?**

*It is also possible, that there is a much better way of doing this. If that is the case, I am open for suggestions too.*

Comment: start with looking into `wp-login.php`

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be messing around with that.
Look at the following hook:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login

You should do something like:

```
function check_test_user() {
// Your code here
}

add_action('wp_login', 'check_test_user');
```

The hook will run as part of the Login process and saves you modifying core Wordpress files.

Comment: you first sentence is just not correct, that is not the file in which the authentication is actually done

Comment: Cheers Mark - I deleted it and left the rest.

Comment: now looking better the other part is also problemattic, wp_login is "called" after the user was authenticated. `wp_authenticate` (or some hokk in it) is probably the one you were thinking of.